# How to get exact character diff between two string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two strings, I want to get difference between contents of two strings in SQL ??

for example,

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='Please check requirement and let me know your feedback.';

Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='Please checkout requirement & let me know your feedback';
```

Result should be like the words which are not common in both the string.

e.g checkout , &

Comment: Reasoning from a single example is problematic. Do you have more examples of expected inputs and the results you're seeking? I.e. are you actually looking for the [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)?

Comment: Ideally, don't just *change* from one example to a completely different one. I asked for multiple examples, and you've removed the example that answers have already been written around.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I though I am not clear about the question , that is why changed the example. I want to find out words that are not common in two string any help appreciated.

Comment: No clear. What do you want to see in the following use-cases: (1) string1 = 'Hello world' string2 = 'What a wonderful world' (2)  string1 = 'stackoverflow.com' string2 = 'stackoverflow'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will first split the strings into single words and then check for words which do not exist in the other string

```
Declare @String1 as varchar(100)='Please check requirement and let me know your feedback.';
Declare @String2 as varchar(100)='Please checkout requirement & let me know your feedback';

WITH s1_Splitted AS
(
    SELECT wrd.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Word
    FROM
    (SELECT (
            SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @String1 AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
            ) AS Casted
    ) AS derived
    CROSS APPLY derived.Casted.nodes('/x') AS A(wrd)
)
,s2_Splitted AS
(
    SELECT wrd.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS Word
    FROM
    (SELECT (
            SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT @String2 AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
            ) AS Casted
    ) AS derived
    CROSS APPLY derived.Casted.nodes('/x') AS A(wrd)
)
SELECT 'only in s1',s1.Word
FROM s1_Splitted AS s1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM s2_Splitted AS s2 WHERE s2.Word=s1.Word)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'only in s2',s2.Word
FROM s2_Splitted AS s2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM s1_Splitted AS s1 WHERE s1.Word=s2.Word)
```

The result (**attention:** the `.` after *feedback* is taken as two different words...)

```
only in s1  and
only in s1  check
only in s1  feedback.
only in s2  &
only in s2  checkout
only in s2  feedback
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE` as the below:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CASE WHEN LEN(@String1) < LEN(@String2) THEN @String2 ELSE @String1 END, 
               CASE WHEN LEN(@String1) < LEN(@String2) THEN @String1 ELSE @String2 END, '')
```

Result: `.com`

Comment: I think you should also do the opposite replacement, since `@String1` can be the bigger string . +1 Though.

Comment: @sagi I thought so

Answer (score 0):

Assuming @String1 is a prefix of @String2

```
select right (@String2,len(@String2)-len(@String1))
;
```

Comment: This is not generic and will work only in the format posted in the question .

Comment: @Sagi, is there a general definition for the difference between 2 strings with a string result? what is the difference between 'stackoverflow' and 'overrated'? between 'apple' and 'banana'?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - as I suggested in the comments, one *common* metric is edit distance, but the OP hasn't really clarified yet what they mean, beyond a magical "I know what the difference is, make the computer know it too"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, therefore "with a string result".  the OP was clear that the requested result,whatever it is, is a string.

Comment: No, but your query will only work for cases when the second string is the same as the first string with extras. The opposite won't work & If the extra is at the beginning it won't work. I'm not talking about difference between 'apple' and 'banana' . BTW - OP edited the question, both answer won't work.

Comment: @sagi, I was very clear - "Assuming String1 is a prefix of String2". You are conveniently choosing a use case that you know how to handle  without knowing if this has any value to the OP. And you are conveniently  ignoring more general use cases that you don't know what to do with.

Comment: It's a pointless argument, besides the fact that I could clearly see from the question that it most likely won't be the only case, he already updated his question and showed that.

Comment: @sagi, when a question is not baked I'm not throwing code at the OP. I'm answering the direct question so the OP could evaluate his use-case and I'm asking for clarifications.