# Oracle - Remove letters from STRING_2 where they exist in STRING_1

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I’m having a bit of a STRING issue and would be very grateful for any assistance; I’d like to compare the letters in STRING_1 with STRING_2, where a match is found, the matched letter will then be removed from STRING_2.

For example, STRING_1 contains a value of `‘MICROSOFT’`, STRING_2 contains a value of `‘MSS’`, I would therefore like the result to show as `‘S’`(as `‘MICROSOFT’` only contains one `‘M’` and one `‘S’`). If STRING_1 contains a value of `‘MISS’`, and STRING_2 contains a value of `‘MISS’`, I would then like the result to show as `NULL`.

However, the query I’m using isn’t quite producing the desired result; using the same example above (`STRING_1 = ‘MICROSOFT’`, `STRING_2 = ‘MSS’`), the output is `NULL`, the `‘S’` value from `‘MICROSOFT’` is removing both instances of the `‘S’` value in `‘MSS’`, I would only like it to only remove one of the `‘S’` values from `‘MSS’`.

Below is an example of the query I’m using;

```
WITH
 TABLE_1 AS (SELECT 'ADVANCED' AS STRING_1,
                    'ANNA' AS STRING_2
               FROM DUAL
             UNION
             SELECT 'MICROSOFT' AS STRING_1,
                    'MSS' AS STRING_2
               FROM DUAL
             UNION
             SELECT 'MICROSOFT' AS STRING_1,
                    'MSOFT' AS STRING_2
               FROM DUAL
             UNION
             SELECT 'MISS' AS STRING_1,
                    'MISS' AS STRING_2
               FROM DUAL)
SELECT T1.*,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(TRANSLATE(T1.STRING_2,T1.STRING_1,RPAD(' ',LENGTH(T1.STRING_2))),'[[:space:]]','') AS RESULT
  FROM TABLE_1 T1
```

Actual Result

[image: Actual Result]

Desired Result

[image: Desired Result]

Apologies if I’ve not explained this clearly enough – feel free to let me know if you need any more information.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will need some dynamic SQL to handle this.

Comment: I'd say create a PL/SQL function `remove(string1, string2)` but I know the response would be "this must be done in pure SQL" :-)

Comment: @TonyAndrews yes , related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502739/how-to-get-exact-character-diff-between-two-string-in-sql

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. @TonyAndrews, pure SQL would be better but if it's not possible, I'd be happy using a function - as long as I can achieve the desired result :) Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a PL/SQL solution as you said you would be happy with that:

```
create or replace function remstr (s1 varchar2, s2 varchar2) return varchar2
is
  len integer := nvl(length(s2),0);
  outstr varchar2(32767) := s1;
  pos integer;
begin
  for i in 1..len loop
    pos := instr(outstr, substr(s2,i,1));
    if pos > 0 then
      outstr := substr(outstr,1,pos-1)||substr(outstr,pos+1);
    end if;
  end loop;
  return outstr;
end;
```

Use like this:

```
WITH
 TABLE_1 AS
 (SELECT 'ADVANCED' AS STRING_1, 'ANNA' AS STRING_2 FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 'MICROSOFT' AS STRING_1, 'MSS' AS STRING_2 FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 'MICROSOFT' AS STRING_1, 'MSOFT' AS STRING_2 FROM DUAL
 UNION
 SELECT 'MISS' AS STRING_1, 'MISS' AS STRING_2 FROM DUAL
 )
SELECT
 T1.*, REMSTR(STRING_2, STRING_1) AS RESULT
FROM
 TABLE_1 T1
```

I tested and got your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, Tony - very much appreciated. I've tested my end but the end result isn't quite right - it appears to only be removing the first matching letter from STRING_2 (e.g. 'ANNA' becomes 'NNA', as opposed to 'N'). I will have a play with the function this afternoon but again, thank you.

Comment: @MAndrews I just corrected my function, please try it again.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks, Tony :)